# Отсортировать словарь, значение которого является списком

Tags: python, структуры-данных

Есть словарь data, ключи которого - ФИО спортсмена, а значение - список результатов, которые он выполняет в разных соревнованиях. Нужно вывести спортсменов от лучшего к худшему в каждом соревновании, включая результат. Получается отсортировать только по самому список в целом, но не по его отдельным элементам.

```
data = {
    'A': [32.01, 14.14, 32.17, 2.2, 4.33],
    'B': [35.78, 14.1, 22.92, 2.1, 3.9],
    'C': [29.35, 13.98, 38.01, 2.32, 4.4],
    'D': [30.22, 13.81, 29.75, 2.35, 4.12],
    'E': [36.92, 14.55, 30.1, 2.1, 3.87],
    'F': [28.8, 13.96, 35.15, 2.3, 4.42],
    'G': [30.0, 13.99, 33.2, 2.29, 4.21]
        }

sorted_people = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
print(sorted_people)
```

Вывод:

```
{'F': [28.8, 13.96, 35.15, 2.3, 4.42],
 'C': [29.35, 13.98, 38.01, 2.32, 4.4],
 'G': [30.0, 13.99, 33.2, 2.29, 4.21],
 'D': [30.22, 13.81, 29.75, 2.35, 4.12],
 'A': [32.01, 14.14, 32.17, 2.2, 4.33],
 'B': [35.78, 14.1, 22.92, 2.1, 3.9],
 'E': [36.92, 14.55, 30.1, 2.1, 3.87]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Непонятно, какой результат считается лучшим - больший или меньший. Я так понял, что результат здесь - время, поэтому сортировал по возрастанию. Если требуется по убыванию, нужно добавить аргумент `reverse=True` в `sorted()`

```
for i in range(len(data['A'])):
    sorted_people = dict(sorted({k:v[i] for k,v in data.items()}.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
    print(f'Соревнование {i+1}: {sorted_people}')
```

```
Соревнование 1: {'F': 28.8, 'C': 29.35, 'G': 30.0, 'D': 30.22, 'A': 32.01, 'B': 35.78, 'E': 36.92}
Соревнование 2: {'D': 13.81, 'F': 13.96, 'C': 13.98, 'G': 13.99, 'B': 14.1, 'A': 14.14, 'E': 14.55}
Соревнование 3: {'B': 22.92, 'D': 29.75, 'E': 30.1, 'A': 32.17, 'G': 33.2, 'F': 35.15, 'C': 38.01}
Соревнование 4: {'B': 2.1, 'E': 2.1, 'A': 2.2, 'G': 2.29, 'F': 2.3, 'C': 2.32, 'D': 2.35}
Соревнование 5: {'E': 3.87, 'B': 3.9, 'D': 4.12, 'G': 4.21, 'A': 4.33, 'C': 4.4, 'F': 4.42}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно с помощью pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")
res = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).index).to_dict("list")
```

res:

```
{0: ['E', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'C', 'F'],
1: ['E', 'A', 'B', 'G', 'C', 'F', 'D'],
2: ['C', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'B'],
3: ['D', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'E'],
4: ['F', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'E']}
```

то есть, получите словарь, в котором ключ - номер соревнования, а значение - список участников по убыванию результата.

Если нужно получить еще и показатели, то можно сделать так:

```
res = dict()
df.apply(lambda x: res.setdefault(x.name, x.sort_values(ascending=False).to_dict()))
```

res:

```
{0: {'E': 36.92, 'B': 35.78, 'A': 32.01, 'D': 30.22, 'G': 30.0, 'C': 29.35, 'F': 28.8},
 1: {'E': 14.55, 'A': 14.14, 'B': 14.1, 'G': 13.99, 'C': 13.98, 'F': 13.96, 'D': 13.81},
 2: {'C': 38.01, 'F': 35.15, 'G': 33.2, 'A': 32.17, 'E': 30.1, 'D': 29.75, 'B': 22.92},
 3: {'D': 2.35, 'C': 2.32, 'F': 2.3, 'G': 2.29, 'A': 2.2, 'B': 2.1, 'E': 2.1},
 4: {'F': 4.42, 'C': 4.4, 'A': 4.33, 'G': 4.21, 'D': 4.12, 'B': 3.9, 'E': 3.87}}
```

Comment: "**вывести** спортсменов от лучшего к худшему в каждом соревновании, **включая норматив**"

Comment: @АлексейР ответ-то я обновил, однако показатели и нормативы - это две большие разницы.

Comment: поправил в вопросе на "результаты". тоже способ :)

Answer (score 2):

сортировка по возрастанию:

```
for t in zip(*data.values()):
    print(dict(sorted(zip(data.keys(),t), key=lambda x: x[1])))
'''
{'F': 28.8, 'C': 29.35, 'G': 30.0, 'D': 30.22, 'A': 32.01, 'B': 35.78, 'E': 36.92}
{'D': 13.81, 'F': 13.96, 'C': 13.98, 'G': 13.99, 'B': 14.1, 'A': 14.14, 'E': 14.55}
{'B': 22.92, 'D': 29.75, 'E': 30.1, 'A': 32.17, 'G': 33.2, 'F': 35.15, 'C': 38.01}
{'B': 2.1, 'E': 2.1, 'A': 2.2, 'G': 2.29, 'F': 2.3, 'C': 2.32, 'D': 2.35}
{'E': 3.87, 'B': 3.9, 'D': 4.12, 'G': 4.21, 'A': 4.33, 'C': 4.4, 'F': 4.42}
```